# how to upload files to a forked version of my gitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I created a repository on gitHub and uploaded my local module to it.

i then invited contributers to join the project. they forked the original repository on gitHub and called it :

> theCopy

i have now substiancially changed the local version of my module (the version on my laptop) and i want to upload it to the  forked version on the gitHub account **('theCopy')**.

I am not clear how to do that

i tried :

```
> git push origin theCopy
```

but nothing happened.

would appricate some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Just push your changes to the main Repo that everyone has synced from and then on the forked account why don't you just run:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

If you haven't setup an upstream:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

You can refer [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) for official documentation. Additionally, I would check out the following resources to learn git:

- [TryGit](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)
- [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/)

Comment: Hi Harsha. i tried  pushing my changes to the orignal but nothign happened. i did this: git push origin master  . but nothing changed . was this the correct comand?#

Comment: Sounds right, however, if you cloned the repository you should be able to get away with 'git push'. Have you added and committed your changes though?

Comment: how do you mean added and commited my changes. do i need to add and commit them on gitHub. if so, how do i do that?

Comment: How are you pushing your updated files? You first need to `git add` your files that have been changed/updated, then `git commit -m "[messege here]"` committing the files, and then `git push` or `git push origin master` them